# CLOB to varchar2 conversion in oracle

Tags: oracle10g, type-conversion

I need to get the result of the below query in varchar2 to display in a view. I tried using dbms_lob.substr as below but then it gives me error  "ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value".

> dbms_lob.substr((select wm_concat(tr_country) from NEXUS_TRAC_TRAVEL_PLAN_DTL 
>   where nexus_year = trdata.nexus_year
>   and nexus_seq_no = trdata.nexus_seq_no),4000,1) ,

The select query is returning result in CLOB.

Answer (score 1):

`WM_CONCAT` returns a `VARCHAR2`, not a `CLOB`. So you can remove the call to `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`.

Comment: If I remove DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR,                                  >SELECT
(trpln.dtc_source||' - '||trpln.dtc_destination)                 union
select
(select wm_concat(tr_country) from NEXUS_TRAC_TRAVEL_PLAN_DTL 
where nexus_year = trdata.nexus_year
and nexus_seq_no = trdata.nexus_seq_no)   Error "Expression must have same datatype as corrosponding expression"

Comment: I want to do union of two select. The first select returns varchar2 SELECT (trpln.dtc_source||' - '||trpln.dtc_destination) and second select result is taken as CLOB

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to 11.2 or higher the `listagg(...)` function may save your day as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39325808/1915920