# Getting ORA-22922 (nonexistent LOB value) or no result at all with wm_concat()

Tags: oracle11g, casting, wm-concat

(Using Oracle 11.2)

I have a rather complicated SQL with something like

```sql
wm_concat( distinct abc )
```

that is expected to **return some `varchar2(4000)` compatible result**.

It causes `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes` in my select used in some `coalesce( some_varchar_col, wm_concat( ... ) )`.

---

So I **tried casting** it via two different methods:

```sql
dbms_lob.substr( ..., 4000 )  -- L) tried even with 3000 in case of "unicode byte blow-up"
cast( ... as varchar2(4000))  -- C) tried even with 3000 in case of "unicode byte blow-up"
```

(The are used in a view, but playing around with it suggests, it is not related to the views)

**Depending on the column and other operators I either get N) no result or O) `ORA-22922`**:

```sql
select * from view_with_above_included where rownum <= 100
```

- N) My Eclipse Data Explorer JDBC connection returns without any result (no columns without results, no `(0 rows effected)`, only the query time statistics). (It could be an internal exception not treated as such?)
- O)

  ```
  ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value
  ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1092
  ORA-06512: in line 1
  ```

---

**Strangely the following test queries work:**

```sql
-- rownum <= 100 would already cause the above problems
select * from view_with_above_included where rownum <= 10
```

or

```sql
select * from view_with_above_included
```

but looking at the actual aggregated data does not show aggregated data that would exceed 1000 characters in length.

Comment: this could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969274, https://community.oracle.com/thread/2383469

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Luckily, it works with the `listagg( ... )` function provided since `11.2`** (we are already running on), so we did not have to investigate further:

```sql
listagg( abc, ',' ) within group ( order by abc )
```

(Where `wm_concat(...)` is, as one should know, some internal and officially unsupported function.)

---

a **[rather nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22624072/1915920)** (because it is not so bloated) **to implement the `distinct` functionality is via self-referencing regexp functionality** which should work in many cases:

```sql
regexp_replace( 
  listagg( abc, ',' ) within group ( order by abc )
, '(^|,)(.+)(,\2)+', '\1\2' )
```

(Maybe/Hopefully we will see some working `listagg( distinct abc )` functionality in the future, which would be very neat and cool like the `wm_concat` syntax. E.g. this is no problem since a long time with Postgres' `string_agg( distinct abc )`<sup>1</sup> )

```sql
-- 1: postgres sql example:
select string_agg( distinct x, ',' ) from unnest('{a,b,a}'::text[]) as x`
```

---

If the **list exceeds 4000 characters**, one **cannot use `listagg` anymore** (`ORA-22922` again).
But luckily we can use the `xmlagg` function here (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29008456/1915920)).
If you want to **realize a `distinct` on a 4000-chars-truncated result** here, you could **outcomment the `(1)`-marked lines**.

```sql
-- in smallercase everything that could/should be special for your query
-- comment in (1) to realize a distinct on a 4000 chars truncated result
WITH cfg AS ( 
  SELECT 
    ','                  AS list_delim,
    '([^,]+)(,\1)*(,|$)' AS list_dist_match,  -- regexp match for distinct functionality
    '\1\3'               AS LIST_DIST_REPL  -- regexp replace for distinct functionality
  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
  --REGEXP_REPLACE( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(             -- (1)
  RTRIM( XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT( E, mycol, listdelim ).EXTRACT('//text()') 
  ORDER BY mycol ).GetClobVal(), LIST_DELIM ) 
  --, 4000 ), LIST_DIST_MATCH, LIST_DIST_REPL )  -- (1)
  AS mylist
FROM mytab, CFG
```

Comment: the **`distinct` however must be dealt with differently**, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11511203/1915920

Comment: wm_concat is anyways unsupported in Oracle11g. it was avaiable till Oracle 10g.

Comment: @Raj_Te: wrong ... removed in Oracle 12c (working in 11.2 e.g.), available, but unsupported where existent.

Comment: I also ran into errors using **wm_concat** on **11.2**, solved with **listagg**, and sub querying to deal with **distinct** values. Thanks!